# Safari not reading submit button Value on Jquery Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, safari

I have the following buttons on my form

```
<button type="submit" id="SearchButton" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Search</button>

<button type="submit" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Clear</button>
```

And the following Scripting on my page

```
$(document).on('submit', '#indexSearchForm', function () {
    //loadingSpinnerStart();


    var submitValue = $("button[type=submit]:focus").val();
    if (typeof submitValue === "undefined") {
        submitValue = "";
    }
    var data = $(this).serialize() + "&submit=" + submitValue;

    //Ajax Submit Code
    return false;
});
```

In the controller code i need to read both submit and reset actions

It works fine in most browsers except Safari (Windows & IOS) where submit value returns as undefined for both Search and reset.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to simply set newval = "Search" so Anirudh answer was sort of right as the Reset button is now a plain button, clears the form, reloads the default search results (none) all by Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

i have an idea...
when u click a button set a variable and call that variable like

```
var newval="";

function search()
{
newval="Search";
//ur rest code
}

function clear()
{
newval="Reset";
//ur rest code
}

$(document).on('submit', '#indexSearchForm', function () {
//loadingSpinnerStart();

if (typeof newval === "undefined") {
    newval = "";
}
var data = $(this).serialize() + "&submit=" + newval;

//Ajax Submit Code
return false;
```

});

```
<button type="submit" id="SearchButton" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="search()">Search</button>

<button type="submit" id="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
```